# Unable to pass AngularJS variable to div modal in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an image gallery where any image when clicked, opens up in an expanded modal box (Bootstrap 3). I've created the div that handles the thumbnail view and the modal dialogue as a template wherein the values are filled using a custom script written in AngularJS.

The problem is, I'm unable to pass the values into the modal dialogue. The thumbnail part of the code works fine but upon clicking the individual images, the values aren't read from the script. This is the HTML code I'm working with:

```
<div class="isotope-container row grid-space-20">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item int-design" ng-repeat="photopost in postCntrl.posts">
        <div class="image-box">
            <div class="overlay-container">
                <img ng-src="{{photopost.photoThumbnailSrc}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                <a class="overlay" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-1">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
                    <span>{{photopost.photoCategory}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-1">{{photopost.photoSubTitle}}</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="project-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="project-1-label" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="project-1-label">{{photopost.photoCaption}}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img ng-src="{{photopost.photoSrc}}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script written using Angular:

```
(function(){

    var postGeneratorApp = angular.module('PhotoPostGenerator', []);

    postGeneratorApp.controller('PhotoPostController', function() {

        this.posts = photoposts;
        this.numOfPosts = 20;

    });

    var photoposts = 
        [
            {
                photoCaption: "This is an image",
                photoSubTitle: "Tree",
                photoTimestamp: 'Aug 23, 2015',
                photoCategory: "landscape",
                photoSrc: "../images/gallery/img1.jpg",
                photoThumbnailSrc: "../images/gallery/img1_th.jpg",
            },

            {
                photoCaption: "This is also an image",
                photoSubTitle: "Bird",
                photoTimestamp: 'Sep 23, 2015',
                photoCategory: "bird",
                photoSrc: "../images/gallery/img2.jpg",
                photoThumbnailSrc: "../images/gallery/img2_th.jpg",
            },
           {...} //more entries such as these
         ];

   })();
```

This is what the gallery thumbnails look like (please ignore the captions on the thumbnails, they are from an earlier snapshot):

[image]

And this is what the modal dialogue looks like, when clicked:

[image]

As you can see the caption and the expanded image are missing (photoCaption and photoSrc). When looking for answers I came across AngularUI for Bootstrap but wasn't sure how to use this or if there was a simpler fix available for my current code.

Comment: Could you setup demo on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: it's part of a larger codebase but ok, I'll try to do it in a bit. I thought the attached snapshots might help explain the situation in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**

Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/mamor/4KBWj/embedded/

In the controller main, when opener the modal use the parameter 'resolve' for pass values between conttroler main and modal. In the modal use the name parameter passed in modalInstance when open.

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {
     $scope.open = function () {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    params: function () {
                        return {
                            key: 'value',
                            key2: 'value2'
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(
                function (result) {
                    console.log('called $modalInstance.close()');
                    alert(result);
                },
                function (result) {
                    console.log('called $modalInstance.dismiss()');
                    alert(result);
                }
            );
        };
});
```

Now uses de params in modal controller for obtains values of main controller.

```
myApp.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'params', function ($scope, $modalInstance, params) {
    console.log(params); /* This params of MainController */

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close('this is result for close');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('this is result for dismiss');
    };
}]);
```

**EDIT 2**

Add in the element call this: "ng-click='clickedElement = photopost'"

```
<div class="image-box">
    <div class="overlay-container">
        <img ng-src="{{photopost.photoThumbnailSrc}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        <a class="overlay" ng-click="clickedElement = photopost" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-1">
            <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
            <span>{{photopost.photoCategory}}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="clickedElement = photopost" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-1">{{photopost.photoSubTitle}}</a>
</div>
```

After, in the modal acess metada of target use 'clickedElement' for acess the data.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    {{clickedElement}}
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="project-1-label">{{clickedElement.photoCaption}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still unable to understand your solution. Could you perhaps elaborate on the explanation and maybe, edit the example to reflect how I could use it in my code?

Comment: Sorry, look for second example